# Battery Historian Error for Checking Power Consumption

Tags: android, python, python-3.x

I want to check the power consumption of my app on an android device and I just came across this link [Battery Historian](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html)

I followed the above tutorial and every step is fine until I reached the last one.

While I executed the last step

> python historian.py batterystats.txt > batterystats.html

It gives me an error as

```
File "Historian.py", Line xx
print "\nUsage: %s [OPTIONS] [FILE]\n" %sys.argv[0]
SyntaxError: Missing parenthesis in call to 'print'
```

The file of batterystats.txt is being generated but batterytstats.html is not being created

NOTE: This is the 1st time I have installed Python on my device just to check the battery consumption. I don't have any idea on this on how to deal with this.

I just checked what might be causing the error and I came to know that the Syntax of Python has changed from 2.x to 3.x. Am using Python Version 3.5.2

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> Next, make sure Python 2.7 (NOT Python 3!) is installed

Install Python 2.7 to use the script and it should work fine.

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/